# What is the equivalent of a Session state in MVVM?

Tags: c#, session, mvvm, windows-store-apps

In ASP.NET web applications the information about the current session like username, permissions, state, and settings that are needed across the entire application or between postbacks can be stored in the session object.  What is the equivalent technique or object for that in MVVM?

From my understanding of MVVM for wpf/windows store apps, the view model is used to store state and there is no concept of a page refresh.  Is it normal then to create a SessionViewModel or UserViewModel to store this information that is needed across multiple view models and/or views for a user?  Wouldn't this require that every view model have a static reference to it?

So far I have created the following view model to store session information related to a user.  So, is it that this view model needs to be passed around some how to other view models and views or is this not how to handle session in MVVM?

```
public class UserViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public User Model
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Model.Username;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.Model.Username == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.Model.Username = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Permission> Permissions
    {
        get;//TODO
        set;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Setting> Settings
    {
        get;//TODO
        set;
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Model.Password;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.Model.Password == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.Model.Password = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public bool Authenticated
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Model.Authenticated;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.Model.Authenticated == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.Model.Authenticated = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }       
    public UserViewModel(User model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its how I've done it. Except to cut down on coding I inherited from a "UserSessionViewModel" with encapsulated this. I'll be interested in seeing what the community has done.

Comment: I won't comment on what is the best practice for storing sessions in MVVM. But if you want a ViewModel "passed around" you can access it easily via the ViewModelLocator. You don't have to pass it as a parameter during navigation.

Another way of doing what you want is to use the isolated storage of the device. Especially if you want some values to persist between activations of the app. However you should encrypt sensitive data in isolated storage

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need a session to store *any* data (I mean related to both presentstion and model layers) then this approach is ok. Of course if it could be split into logical pieces try to do it.

How do you access this object? I would probably use IOC container to get reference for it. Or even better share smth like this between view models

```
public interface IUserContext
{
    UserViewModel Current { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net, the current session (accessible from `HttpContext.Current`) is nothing more than a `static` instance that can be accessed, as it is static, from anywhere.

In MVVM, you could just do the same. Build whatever object you need (you can name it `CurrentSession`), make it `static`, and access it from your view models. Do note this object doesn't *have* to be a ViewModel itself (unless you really need to bind its properties on a view).

Say for example you have a `LoginViewModel` ViewModel for the `Login` view. You could populate your `CurrentSession` object in the `ValidateUser` method of this ViewModel, if the user credentials are valid. Then, anywhere in your viewModels, you could access this `CurrentSession` object.

Comment: Just a precision : HttpContext.Current is not static, it's [ThreadStatic]. It's static inside the scope of a thread. Not at the AppDomain scope.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a [service locator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) pattern?

In your arbitrary viewmodel, you'll receive the service locator, and do something like this:

```
public ArbitraryViewModelCtor(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
{
   var authService = serviceLocator.GetAuthenticationService();
   var currentLoggedInuser = authService.GetCurrentUser();
}
```

[This seems quite interesting.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx)